# File sync between work and home, Windows and Mac, when cloud storage is restricted

Tags: windows, macos, sync, cloud-storage

What is a reliable and convenient way to keep all work related files accessible at a Windows PC at work (no admin rights) and a Mac laptop at home (full admin rights), when access to cloud storage is restricted at work?

I work with statistical modelling at a university that provides individual users with very limited space on its servers and does not not allow the installation of Google Drive or Dropbox. I can therefore access cloud storage only with a web browser, not with File Explorer or the software (RStudio) that runs my analyses.

My current solution is to sync hard drives with a memory stick using Robocopy on the PC and rsync on the Mac. This means I have to run a sync command four times a day, which is prone to user error: I have accidentally lost a full day's work by giving the wrong sync command. Synchronization itself is also not 100% reliable, as I found out when an earlier version of Robocopy did not copy all files under special circumstances.

Can you suggest a better solution to the file access/synchronization problem under similar restrictions?

I asked this question at the Workplace SE, but was directed here instead. Please notice that I work at a university, not in a company, so I cannot expect any help from the employer IT-services.

Answer (score 0):

The following software are designed for exactly this scenario, first one is commercial and the other is open source:

- resilio sync
- syncthing

I'm not putting the link in here. Google for the name, first hit should be it.

Comment: Thanks! I need to look closer into Syncthing, as it seems to allow portable installation and run from an external hard drive. As said, I lack admin rights and cannot install any programs on the work PC.